# Style / Satellite - Is it possible to have Two different aesthetics on different zoom levels?

Tags: mapbox

I am using mapbox to develop a map for a project, the map is being programmed with a global zoom out view and markers that allow you to click and zoom into the area (unclick and zoom out), basically it toggles between two views or zoom distances.

I want the close up view to be the satellite imagery. But the satellite imagery is confusing on the global view - and it would be better to move from a Mapbox style (dark / light) then when you click on a pointer you zoom into the satellite imagery.

Do let me know if this functionality exists and if possible pointers on how to implent?

Thanks! 
B

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to listen for zoom change. Once the zoom event has finished, the [zoomEnd callback](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:zoomend) will be triggered.

In this callback you can get the zoom using the [getZoom() method](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#getzoom). Depending on your zoom level you can [set your style.](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setstyle) (e.g. Satellite or non-satellite)

```js
// Initialize the map
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({ // map options });
// Set an event listener that fires
// just after a zoom transition finishes.
map.on('zoomend', function() {
  
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  if(zoom < 10){
      map.setStyle("mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your style in Mapbox Studio as a non-satellite style, but then add Mapbox Satellite as a layer with min zoom set such that it only shows up once zoomed in.